# Salesforce Adobe Merge Mapping

Tags: salesforce

I am getting this error while performing merge mapping on Salesforce:

> Error:
>   Error saving the merge mapping: Upsert failed. First exception on row 18; first error: STORAGE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED, storage limit exceeded: []

Can someone help me fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the error message is clearly. It seems that your storage in your Salesforce Org is reached and the document is too big. 
Go to **Setup** -> **Data Management** -> **Storage Usage** and check your available storage.

Comment: That was helpful. Thank you